Can't see my wifi settings on my Ubuntu 22.04 and also my Bluetooth is refusing to turn on. What could be the problem and how do I resolve these?
I use my phone's hotspot to access the internet on my laptop through the WiFi connectivity. Unfortunately, the WiFi no longer appears on the laptop and the Bluetooth doesn't turn on. I'm currently frustrated because am unable to check on the problem since the internet (wifi) is not showing. What could be the problem and what do I do?

Restart your network manager and try again ```sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager


Can you use USB tethering on the phone to get computer connected?

there are a couple of things you can try initially:

shutdown your computer, then restart it, or,
log out of Linux then login again.

i have had the network icon disappear from the right side of the taskbar on a couple of odd occasions, and restarting linux or logging off then on again has generally fixed it. since it has only ever happened rarely there was little need to pursue a more complex solution.
please do report back if either of these solutions work for you, or if you have already tried them.
